# Ajax .open returns empty error

Tags: php, ajax, firefox

I am updating my website to HTML 5. I had an Ajax script that called a PHP file, but it now doesn't work. The Firefox web developer add-on just throws an empty error containing only the line number. The line number points to the following line:

```
arequest.open('GET','userrating.php?h=' + h,true);
```

Here is the full script:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
    var activexmodes = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        for(var i = 0; i < activexmodes.length; i++){
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i]);
            } catch(e){
                //suppress error
            }
        }
    } else if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function resetRating(h){
    var arequest = new ajaxRequest();
    arequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(arequest.readyState == 4){
            if(arequest.status == 200 && window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
                var response = arequest.responseText;
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
    h = encodeURIComponent(h);
    arequest.open('GET','userrating.php?h=' + h,true);
    arequest.send(null);
}
```

I know I am passing the correct value for 'h' and that the userrating.php page works absolutely fine with that value. I have tried a few different Ajax scripts now and they all give the same blank error on the .open line of the script.

Can anyone please give me any pointers?

Thanks in advance, Ian

Comment: You can just use `var arequest = ajaxRequest();` without the `new` keyword.

Comment: The code seems correct, could you show us the "updated" header of your html page

Comment: The condition inside resetRating, window.location.href.indexOf ("http") == -1. You use it in the environment where you are testing?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Sheikh, Taking out the "new" didn't make a difference. Mate, How do I get the updated header? I actually added that condition in as an extra check after trying to find out what the error was. Removing it makes no difference.

Comment: Mate, I downloaded an add-on for Firefox that gives live header information, but it showed absolutely no change when the function was called.